# How do you access the model errors on the client side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't like the built in Html.ValidationSummary helper because I want a single message displayed at the top of my form such as...

*There are validation errors. The invalid fields have been highlighted.*

The built in ValidationSummary either doesn't output anything at all or outputs a list of all the fields.  I just want a succinct message.

I have a div at the top of my form styled the way I want it and then when the page loads I hook the following method onto the form...

```
function CheckFormForValidationErrors() 
{
    if (!$("form").valid()) 
    {
        $(".validation-notification").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
}
```

This works great when there are validation errors on the client.  The problem is when the client side validation succeeds but the server side validation such as a login form.  If the user enters a proper username and password the form validation succeeds but the login fails.  On the server side I am adding a model error like so...

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Login failed");
```

But I can't figure out how to get the message to display on the client.  If you have a better idea to accomplish my goal then I'm willing to scrap my idea and change course.  What I'm trying to do shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a whole myriad of options. If just you want to display the message create by this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Login failed");
```

You simply need this in your view:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage(String.Empty)
```

This will however wrap the message in a `<span class="field-validation-error"></span>` but the default styles can be easily overridden if you so desire.

However based on the use-case that you describe above, what it sounds like you need is simply a static(ish) legend that explains "*There are validation errors. The invalid fields have been highlighted.*" whenever there are one or more validation failures on the screen.

So how about this:

```
namespace MvcApplication.Web.Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        private const string ValidationLegendHtml = 
            "<div class=\"validation-legend\">{0}</div>";
        private const string DefaultValidationLegend =
            "There are validation errors. The invalid fields have been highlighted";

        public static MvcHtmlString ValidationLegend(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string message = DefaultValidationLegend)
        {
            if(htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new MvcHtmlString(String.Format(ValidationLegendHtml, message));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the view you simply need to insert:

```
@Html.ValidationLegend()    //Use the default legend message
@Html.ValidationLegend("Something went wrong!")    //Specific message
```

This will then display the legend if the form is invalid and be totally invisible when its valid!

You will also need to add the namespace of the new extension to your **Views**/web.config (don't confuse with the root web.config) like so:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

    <!-- Add Me! -->
    <add namespace="MvcApplication.Web.Extensions"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Unfortunately this won't give you intellisense for the new extension method, if this is important you can alternatively (or additionally) add a using statement for the extension to the top of your view immediately after the `@model` declaration like so:

```
@model MvcApplication.Web.Models.LoginModel
@using MvcApplication.Web.Extensions
```

**EDIT**

If you want to support showing this client side as well change the extension to:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationLegend(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string message = DefaultValidationLegend)
{
    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
    tagBuilder.SetInnerText(message);
    tagBuilder.AddCssClass("validation-legend");

    if(htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass("hide");
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Make sure you have a `.hide { display: none; }` CSS rule.

**EDIT Again**

You can leave it up to jquery.validate to show/hide the legend for you automatically by setting the default value of the errorContainer config setting to match the legend's CSS class. This can be done by declaring the script includes like so:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ errorContainer: '.validation-legend' });
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note the setDefaults call that comes *after* the jquery.validate script tag but *before* the jquery.validate.unobtrusive script tag.  This order is important.  Also note that any validation error will show all .validation-legends, so if you have any screens with two different validation-legends you might need to get a bit more fancy.

Comment: I tried your example and it works well except it doesn't work for client side validation. If I type invalid values the fields turn red as I want then to but no message at the top. If I try to login with invalid credentials it shows up. I'm trying to get a message to show up for both client side validation errors **and** server side validation errors.

Comment: Sorry, you edited your answer and I didn't see it before I changed my comment. I will try your suggestion but I think you made the connection I was missing.

Comment: Please see my updated answer which also show/hide the legend for you automatically on client-side errors too!

Answer (score 7):

When you're in your view, the ModelState is located in the ViewData

```
 ViewData.ModelState
```

And to get the error messages:

```
 foreach(string key in ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
 {
     foreach (var error in ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
     {
         string err = error.ErrorMessage;
     }
 }
```

and in Razor, maybe this will work (my Razor is rusty)

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <ul>
    @foreach (string key in ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
    {
        @foreach (var error in ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
        {
            <li>@error.ErrorMessage</li>
        }
    }
    </ul>
}
```